# How to delay the jquery parts so they dont come on all at the same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, settimeout, delay

I want the `.title` to come on then the `.element` to come on and then the `.list`. But, I can't seem to figure out how to do it. They always come on at the same time.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $("#screen" + screenNum).show();
  $("#screen" + screenNum + " .title").each(function(index) {
    $(this).css("display", "block");
    TweenLite.from($(this), animationSpeed, {
      x: -1000,
      ease: Cubic.easeOut,
      delay: index * 0.1
    });
  });

  $("#screen" + screenNum + " .element").each(function(index) {
    $(this).css("display", "block");
    TweenLite.from($(this), animationSpeed, {
      y: 1080,
      ease: Cubic.easeOut,
      delay: index * 0.1
    });
  });

  $("#screen" + screenNum + " .list").each(function(index) {
    $(this).css("display", "block");
    TweenLite.from($(this), animationSpeed, {
      y: -500,
      ease: Cubic.easeOut,
      delay: index * 0.1
    });
  });
}, numEle * 100);
```

Comment: I think that's because your timeout includes everything. If you do it separately it will work. Or you tweek the delay, Because I think that the delay is equal for every action

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the `.load` function in `jquery`, what it does is the second something finishes loading it will run a function. you can use it to say only run a function when document loads, run it when an object on the page loads or even another javascript function. to use it just reference the object with

```
$("object here").load(function);
```

or

```
$("object").load(function(){

});
```

here's the w3schools page if you wish to know more: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_load.asp